# Which charset should i use

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I've got a problem in searching for characters like `ì`, `í`, `î` and `ï` or `ô` and `ó` etc. are the same.

I tried to use `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_unicode_ci` but in both charsets my database thinks `Tînker` = `Tïnker` = `Tínkér` = `Tinkèr`.

Could somebody tell me which the right charset is to manage all the exiting little dots and dashes in MySQL?

Example:
A user named "`Tînker`" with id 2 is stored and the result for `SELECT id FROM chars WHERE name = 'Tinkèr' LIMIT 1` is `2`.

Comment: Could you improve your question by posting your search query?

Comment: A user named Tînker with id 2 is stored and the result for "SELECT id FROM chars WHERE name = 'Tinkèr' LIMIT 1" is 2

Comment: It is generally a good idea to *edit* you question above when you provide more information, so people don't have to look in the comments for it.

Comment: thank you ;) question is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `BINARY` before your comparison, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM chars WHERE BINARY name = '...'
```